# Hapijs serve base64 image

Tags: javascript, base64, hapi.js

I'm trying to serve a base64 image to the user using hapijs and have no idea why code below doesn't work, any suggestions?

```
server.route({
  method: 'GET',
  path: '/image',
  handler: function (request, reply) {
    var b64str="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhPQBEAPeoAJosM//AwO/AwH...";
    var buf = new Buffer(b64str, 'base64');

    reply(buf).bytes(buf.length).header('Content-type', 'image/gif');
  }
});
```

Comment: Have you tried stripping `data:image/gif;base64,` from the `b64str` before passing it to the `Buffer`?

Answer (score 1):

First, You need to remove "data:image/gif;base64" from the string.

Second, If you are using hapi v17:

```
server.route({
  method: 'GET',
  path: '/image',
  handler: function (req, h) {
    const b64str= 'R0lGODlhPQBEAPeoAJosM//AwO/AwH...';
    const buf = Buffer.from(b64str, 'base64');
    return h.response(buf).type('image/png').bytes(buf.length).code(200);
  }
});
```

**Keep in mind:**
[new Buffer(array) is deprecated](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_new_buffer_array) so use Buffer.from(array) instead.

Comment: Please note that if b64str starts with data:image/png;base64,iVBORw... you need to cut it. const buf = Buffer.from(b64.split(',')[1], 'base64');

Answer (score 0):

you have to remove data:image/gif;base64 from your b64 str.
try this code it works.if you need any further info,I am happy to help

```
server.route({
  method: 'GET',
  path: '/image',
  handler: function (request, reply) {
    var b64str="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";
    var buf = new Buffer(b64str, 'base64');

    reply(buf).bytes(buf.length).header('Content-type', 'image/png').header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=h.png');
  }
});
```

if you want to send gif then you need to change content-type to image/gif and filename to yourfilename.gif